# is it possible to pin AIR app over any opened windows?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I need to pin AIR application over other windows, I mean, regardless if AIR application is in focus or not, it must not hide, it always must be shown, whatever other program I activate or work with, AIR application must be over every window always. Is it possible? If it is, please show me the function (example code will be better :) ) which does it, incase if AS3 has one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`alwaysInFront`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#alwaysInFront) property of the [`NativeWindow`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) class:

> The `alwaysInFront` property specifies whether this window will always be in front of other windows (including those of other applications).
>
> - *The following example forces a window to be displayed in front of all
>     other windows (that are not similarly forced to the front):*
>     `windowObj.alwaysInFront = true;`
> - *Another example with a reference to a display object on the window stage:*
>     `displayObject.stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront=true;`

Comment: yes, that is what i was looking for, just example is the same what is written in link, this is adobe example,not practical.. thank u