# Sending my AS3 AIR application window in front of everything

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, desktop

I tried searching for this but nothing worked.

I'm trying to make my AIR application window to be always visible on top of every other windows.

I read about `alwaysInFront`, but I can't get it to work.
I am using an AS3 Class file on AIR 20.0 for Desktop.

My code looked like this:
I imported `flash.desktop.NativeApplication;` and in the first function I added `windowObj.alwaysInFront = true;`.

It did not work, saying `windowObj` is not a thing. How do I do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Include the code you have tried. You already got one answer to this question so it would be good to include a link to that question at least and even better to actually show what you tried.

Comment: You're looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39491103/3709765) :)

Comment: I tried doing the windowObj.alwaysInFront = true; it says windowObj isn't a thing

Comment: @ProgramKiddo that comment should be part of your question. Edit your question to include this. What you have tried and why it isn't working is very relevant.

Comment: @NealDavis Edited ;)

Comment: @someOne yeah I was looking at this before, tried doing it and didn't succeed xD

Comment: !! The `displayObject` or the `windowObj` mentioned in the samples, are _not_ literals, they're some _placehoders_ for any of your "display objects" or of "your window object", respectively!! As another approach, however, you may try `stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront=true;` :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to pin AIR app over any opened windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489071/is-it-possible-to-pin-air-app-over-any-opened-windows)

Comment: @someOne Oh, I see. I didn't understand that windowObj was a placeholder, works perfectly now. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
this.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = true;
```